# Call .NET objects/dlls across virtual sites

Tags: .net

Site 1 has dll's for x amount of object and data calls.  Can Site 2 (a separate .net web app) call the objects/dll's of Site 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be more semantics:

You can't call an object of another process.  You can however potentially instantiate a class within a dll as long as there is a reference to that dll in the calling web application.

If you GAC the dll, the classes (not objects) will be accessible to the entire machine.

Answer (score 0):

I never used .NET Remoting but isn't that the kind of problem it could solve?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the situation was that because you couldn't access the Bin directory cross site, you'd need to develop an api or web service. Your best bet is to have a local copy of the dll on each server.